# Why does a non-trivial member require defining the constructor for an anonymous union in the same class

Tags: c++, c++17, linker-errors, unions

In the following code (https://wandbox.org/permlink/j9tN0hQzINa3W7cl)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class A {
public:
    A() {
        cout << "A::A()" << endl;
    }
    ~A() {
        cout << "A::~A()" << endl;
    }
};

class B {
public:
    ~B() {}

    void set() {
        new (&a_) A{};
    }

    void destroy() {
        a_.~A();
    }

    union {
        A a_;
    };
    A a2_{}; // (1)
};

int main() {
    auto b = B{};
}
```

An invariant in the above code is that through the construction and destruction of an instance of type `B`, if the element in the variant is set, someone will call destroy() to destroy the element in the union.

Why does the presence of (1) require an explicit definition of the destructor of the anonymous union in B?  The linker raises an error with this code when compiled as is

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "B::'unnamed'::~()",
```

Is this a bug in clang? This code compiles fine with gcc (https://wandbox.org/permlink/QvdJNWyrtG8gf9EE)

Comment: Why were the comments deleted for this question?  Is there a new tradition in SO these days?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot really reproduce the exact problem you describe. Whether the line you maked with `// (1)` is present or not does not have any effect on whether the compiler will accept the code or not in any of my tests. Also, I don't get a linker error but rather a compiler error noting that the destructor is defined as deleted.

[Try it out here](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSAbAQwDtRkBSAJgCFufSAZ1QBXYskwgA5NwDMeFsgYisAag6yAwnlSCCxTEwC2G7BwAMAQTkKlKzOq1HMRkgE9TF61ZGCFwVT10EBRRAg0%2BHz82QIJgkEwWdAYIry8lJkFBVUt1AHZIywAHEQAjBjxkEC9VWpyIAEp8wrrW1TQRAkdNDU11Li5LEMtG7i5u3tVE5NSrVo48gBEauoA/EaaFlrbajq7eybGhkHXRgYmtKaSU2W3aheWrB9nvSwys1R5mrxLyyuq5mseI1vksVvdAbURCwdCxvpC2rkmAB9F7zMG3cGqAD02JyqiYXFRBWemKeGMKXgUXSMTAUIK2WKYnVQqlKjkWn0ZFLSYKsUgajGkAFYpKQWNJzGLUNIerx%2BIFROIHHJaGKCJKBYKANYgAAswoAdAAOWRm80W80ANiFUj1YqMdHM5nFmtIMqkYsEIBdGqkUsFcFgMEQoSMRTwDEwZAoEDQ4cj0ZQzDYxudpAAZpGCNHvRBSm7SgomMQ3NI1aR484WAQAPIsBhl/1irC0thRt34AzIAh4ABumG9zdImAAHphkJ1JFIK9TMAw3RVSsQS25NBhpxX9HhHTOBYxWOx%2BPxGHhSt7IILUEVe6gWEOALRBDSLTjy3hcJiqB%2B12RepUSHQgoLlIoqusOHqjsaVoPlaertCmATGoa5goaoEC4IQJD9LI9CqOuCZRsQOG0E0cp8Lw6qag0OogFwwq2vapCOsKLoShB0hej6pB%2BgGpBBqGYQlAQ5CUPGEZEXQI74EQxBSQA7iuRTlvuIFgexUrutIqqqPJhAIKoUEwXBCGHqoyGoZpvFaqQCCGFgcmNIxDogKx4GaR6XG%2BtRtFcHkKGmpaQU2iBf7udKnE8dR/EhgJEBIOJiYxmJqCEUmwCmpm2a5pQBbDkWLCriplapdWdYNk2mmtoeHbDl2E69gOQ6aWOE5TsVc4gZpS4rqW65YMV267mqwGHigx68Ke57wFeN6wo%2Bz6yK%2BE08J%2B36/v%2BYiAaRtrqW6kHQbB8HAMgyDmYasjoZhskkaQ%2BGpRJ0Y4VwZErVRzY0bZ9lJk5up%2BQFQXBc5zGuWx%2B2Rd63kfTF8DxSAQmdKJcYPUldHSVhcn0IpTDKXuwEimKGkRTIXCyOMekEAZRlHaoJ1nchYXWZ9dlMA5lD43aLluUTWmekI3FM75/nmIFgPWraYU855UUfRzXCE%2BDfOC6QA7EH4d76kAA%3D%3D)

That being said, this does appear to be a bug in clang. Based on [[class.dtor]\9](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.dtor#9) the destructor of `B` should *not* call the destructor of the *variant member* `a_`…

Comment: `B` doesn't have an implicitly defined destructor. It has a user-provided destructor with an empty body.

Comment: Oh, I overlooked that up there, thanks for pointing that out!